# How to Find value from cell and placing corresponding value to another cell using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I need help to write code for Finding value from cell and placing corresponding value to another cell

Suppose cell A contain data like mention below

ControlM : servername :jobname : failure type (Ended not OK, longrunning ...)

I want to check failure type from cell content and placed certain associated value in another cell.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you want is:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","")))))
```

Obviously change "A1" for whatever cell you're referencing.

You can use VBA to insert this formula into the cell that you want to value to appear in.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want but try this:

```
Sub printErrorCode()

Dim errorType, errorCode As Variant 'define two variant variable to store errors and codes
Dim errorPosition As Integer 'define errorPosition which will return the position of the searched string

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName") 'In my example I worked with a single sheet so I will avoid specifying the workbook and the sheet in every line

errorType = .Range("ListOfErrorsRange").Value 'store possible error types
errorCode = .Range("ListOfErrorCodesRange").Value 'store associated codes

For i = LBound(errorType) To UBound(errorType) 'from the first error type to the last
    errorPosition = InStr(1, .Range("YourStringRange"), errorType(i, 1), vbTextCompare) 'return the position of errorType String in YourRange string if found, or 0 if not found
    If errorPosition <> 0 Then 'if errorPosition <>0 it found the string
        .Range("YourStringRange").Offset(0,1).Value = errorCode(i, 1) 'if errorType string found return corresponding errorCode
        Exit Sub 'exit the routine
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Error Not Found In List" 'if errorPosition = 0 for all i, then the Error was not on the list of errors

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code you need to paste in module

```
Public Function getcontent(r As Range) As String
    str1 = InStr(r.Cells.Value, "failure type")
    If str1 > 0 Then
        str2 = Mid(r.Cells.Value, str1 + 13, Len(r.Cells.Value))
        getcontent = str2
    Else
        getcontent = ""
    End If
End Function
```

assume the content "ControlM : servername :jobname : failure type (Ended not OK, longrunning ...)" in cell A1

in Cell A2, =getcontent(A1)

you will get the failure type content alone.

Hope this is inline with your requirements.